# Add class if list item includes x element

Tags: jquery, css

Got a quick one, hopefully. I have these two list items included below. The font color for the royalHtmlContent is grey, but I need the font color to be white if it has royalImage within the royalSlide list item.

```
<li class="royalSlide" style="height: 420px; width: 610px; ">
<div class="royalHtmlContent">Text</div>
</li>

<li class="royalSlide" style="height: 420px; width: 610px; ">
<img class="royalImage" src="#" width="610" height="420" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; ">
<div class="royalHtmlContent royalHtmlContentOverlay">Text text text</div>
</li>
```

I tried this, but it's not working... it's just applying the class (which will have the style for white font color) to all the royalHtmlContent. I need it to do this only if it has royalImage within the list too.

```
if ($('.royalSlide').has('.royalImage')) {
    $('.royalHtmlContent').addClass('royalHtmlContentOverlay');
}
```

Thanks in advance,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work for two reasons (prioritized)

- A jQuery selection alwyas returns a selection and never a falsy value so the condition is always met
- the selection used in the if is independant of the selection inside the if.

Start by selecting the image. If the selection is empty the rest of the chain will not do anything

```
$(".royalSlide > .royalImage").next("div.royalHtmlContent")
                              .addClass('royalHtmlContentOverlay');
```

Comment: I had to correct the class names (lower/uppercase was wrong in your answer) but the theory works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img.royalImage').next('div.royalHtmlContent').addClass('royalHtmlContentOverlay');
```

Think that may work too? Basically just looks for all the  and if theres one there, adds a class to the div, where you can style it with css.